# Can I reference a class in <bindingElementExtensions>?

Tags: c#, wcf-binding

I am trying to setup a custom `GZipMessageEncoder` in an application project; and instead of creating a new project for the `GZipMessageEncoder` classes, I was adding the classes to the application project.  When I get to adding the `<bindingElementExtensions>` tag in the app.config, it gives me the following error:

> The type '[Namespace].GZipMessageEncodingElement' registered for extension 'gzipMessageEncoding' could not be loaded.

When I move the classes into their own project, I receive an entirely different error non-configuration related.

1. In the `app.config` can I reference the class file containing the `GZipMessageEncoder` or is it required to be in its own project?

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter, if those classes placed in different assembly or defined in the application project. Though separating them to their own assemblies might be good idea from design stand point, but that's not important for the problem at hand. Make sure, that [Namespace] is pointing to the namespace, where GZipMessageEncodingElement(and GZipEncoder for that matter) is actually residing. WCF is looking for the specified namespace in config file and if file, where class is defined, contains different namespace, then app.config WCF would complain, that it could not find the class in the specified namespace.